# Getting the names and datatypes of local variables

Tags: java

I have a java code which gets the function names, their return types, their parameters as well as the static variables of a java class. Now I am stuck with getting the names and datatypes of local variables of the methods in the java class. It would be great if you guys would help me out...

Comment: You need to be more specific than that.

Comment: Please show us at least an example of the expected result...

Comment: Similar question [have been asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759095/is-there-a-way-to-identify-the-variables-being-used-within-a-java-method).

Basically, you need to debug, as the local variables are not part of the class, but the thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to extract the local variable names and their types is to example the debug infomation (assuming its there) in the byte code.  You can use a tool like ASM to examine the byte code. Its much harder than using reflection so this is rarely done. ;)

Comment: Can I use JPDA(Java Platform Debugger Architecture) to get the data types of the local variables?

Comment: If you are debugging the application, yes. I suspects its easier to read the byte code, unless you need the values as well.