# java - cannot get field with different initialize

Tags: java, class, reflection, field

I have some problem. I don't know what a calling of like this.

```
class test{
    JButton button=new JButton("button");
    JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser() {
        @Override
        public void approveSelection(){
        File f = getSelectedFile();
           if(f.exists() && getDialogType() == SAVE_DIALOG){
                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,"The file exists, overwrite?","Existing file",JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION);
                switch(result){
                    case JOptionPane.YES_OPTION:
                        super.approveSelection();
                        return;
                    case JOptionPane.NO_OPTION:
                        cancelSelection();
                        return;
                    case JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION:
                        return;
                    case JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION:
             //         cancelSelection();
                        return;
                }
            }
            super.approveSelection();
        }        
    };
    void test()
    {
    }
}
```

So, I have use reflection to get field:

```
Class cls=Class.forName("test");
Field[]field=cls.getDeclaredFields();
for(Field f : field) {
    System.out.println (f.getType().getSimpleName()+ " : "+ f.getType());
}
```

The output is following:

```
JButton : class javax.swing.JButton
JFileChooser : class javax.swing.JFileChooser
```

So, How to get all Object classes inside initialize of JFileChooser like `File f`, `JOptionPane`, etc ?

Comment: the code you have will print all the fields declared in the class. The classes accessed by the code inside the class have nothing to do with declared fields.

Comment: so, what should i do to get them ???

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @JB Nizet : i have no idea, i just know using reflection.

Comment: If you don't even know what you want to do, how can you help you doing it? `File f` is a local variable of a method of an inner class of test. There is no way you get information about this variable using reflection.

Comment: is there any other way ???, maybe using another api like BCEL ???

Comment: Yes, that's it. See [Is there a way to identify the variables being used within a Java method?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759095/is-there-a-way-to-identify-the-variables-being-used-within-a-java-method).

Comment: @saka1029 : it seem identiified variable inside method, but how with my problem ???

Comment: @saka1029 : my problem using initialize of object class, and that link cannot help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample code using BCEL.  An anonymous inner class has an independent name from the outer class.  Its name is `stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1` in this sample.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.bcel.*;

public class SampleBcel {

    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        File f = new File("temp.txt");
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try (BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f))) {
                String line;
                while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JavaClass runnableClass = Repository.lookupClass("stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1");
        System.out.println(runnableClass); 
        Method[] runnableMethods = runnableClass.getMethods();
        for (Method method : runnableMethods) {
            System.out.println("** method : " + method);
            LocalVariableTable local = method.getLocalVariableTable();
            System.out.println(local);
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
class stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1 extends java.lang.Object
implements      java.lang.Runnable
filename        stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1
compiled from       SampleBcel.java
compiler version    52.0
access flags        32
constant pool       87 entries
ACC_SUPER flag      true

Attribute(s):
    SourceFile(SampleBcel.java)
    (Unknown attribute EnclosingMethod: 00 54 00 00)
    InnerClass:stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1("<not a member>", "<anonymous>")

2 fields:
    java.io.File f
    final synthetic stackoverflow.SampleBcel this$0

2 methods:
    void <init>(stackoverflow.SampleBcel)
    public void run()

** method : void <init>(stackoverflow.SampleBcel)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 0, length = 23, index = 0:stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1 this)
** method : public void run()
LocalVariable(start_pc = 0, length = 94, index = 0:stackoverflow.SampleBcel$1 this)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 23, length = 41, index = 3:java.io.BufferedReader r)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 26, length = 8, index = 4:String line)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 41, length = 3, index = 4:String line)
LocalVariable(start_pc = 89, length = 4, index = 1:java.io.IOException e)
```